# Difference between right ”in” something and right ”to” something

Tags: prepositions

In the context of a software development agreement, where it is stated that ”Vendor hereby assigns to Customer all its rights, title and interest in and to the Software”. My question is more on the grammatical construction, rather than the contractual implications.

Comment: Please could you provide some context? For one thing, I have no idea what sort of thing the "something" is; for another, "right" has several meanings, and I don't know which one you mean.

Comment: Hi Rosie, my apologies for the lack of clarity. I’ve added the context. Hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: As @WS said. Though it's not that much a legal thing.

Comment: "Software procurement and development decisions, standards-development policies, telecommunications and information and communication technology policies are all affected by how **IP rights in software** are provided, licensed and enforced." WIPO (https://www.wipo.int/wipo_magazine/en/2008/06/article_0006.html)

Comment: I'd say it's ungrammatical, but the grammatical tweaked form might be verging on unacceptable as outlandish. It probably needs bullet points to correctly allocate prepositions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is the two prepositions refer to "rights, title and interest" in the following way:

*rights/title **to** the Software*

*interest **in** the Software*

Comment: Thought it's just the way they go together: you have _rights **to** something_, but you have _interest **in** something_. The meaning is the same for all, they are now all assigned to Customer.

Comment: "Rights" are not exactly the same as "interests". So can we deduce that it means "...all its rights and title to, and interest in the software..."? Now that I have re-read the question, I'm thinking that that is what it is saying. So, yes your response is valid. Apologies I will delete my earlier comments and upvote your answer.

Comment: In that case, the sentence construction is incorrect.

Comment: @WS2 See also my comment above. I feel there's indeed a (if subtle) difference between "rights **in**" and "rights **to**" and the authors have covered both the cases for ample precaution. Your (now deleted) comment at OP was right, after all. I'd just upvoted it and added my comment in support while you were deleting it.

Comment: @Kris But I think it is saying "rights and title to, and interest in". I agree that "rights" and "title" will take either "in" or "to", and to begin with I thought that was what it was about. (I don't believe there is much difference between "rights to" and "rights in" - which was my point). It could have been expressed better, I would agree. But it probably satisfies the needs of clarity.

Comment: WIPO refers to "one's rights **in** software" -- cited in my comment at OP.

Comment: This is very useful, thanks guys!

Comment: Kris is right, it seems badly written. Just a piece of this awkward legal style to discourage you from reading the small fonts.